Classical limits of Quantum Electrodynamics?
Quantum Electrodynamics is the theory that studies the interactions between matter and radiation (somewhat).
How would one explain for example the movement of an electron in a constant electric field using quantum electrodynamics?

Solving for these specific cases is one of those heroic stories that made Feynman's legend. Some form of the ladder approximation would lead to such limits.

Do you know where I could read on the topic?

@naturallyInconsistent I, too, would be interested in this. Do you have a reference by any chance?

@dennismoore94 Feynman's Nobel lecture covered some stories, though not the case you are looking for. https://www.nobelprize.org/prizes/physics/1965/feynman/lecture/ As for the constant electric field, you can look at https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0312304
